# What is the difference between interface signals and interface ports?

Tags: interface, port, system-verilog

Suppose we have an interface like this:

```
interface Memory_i(input Clock);

    Data_t InData;
    Data_t OutData;
    Address_t Address;

    // To memory controller
    modport Master
    (
        input Clock,
        output InData,
        input OutData,
        output Address
    );

    // To memory
    modport Slave
    (
        input Clock,
        input InData,
        output OutData,
        input Address,
    );

endinterface
```

Is there any significant difference between `Clock` (interface port) and, let us say, `InData` (interface signal)? I know that these entities are connected differently when an interface is instantiated. But is there something else? I also noticed that interface ports are frequently used for the clock signal. Is there a reason for that?

**UPDATE**

I simplified my interface and made two examples where I am trying to use clock in two different ways. I got two slightly different RTL circuits, but I cannot not see any fundamental difference between them.

*Clock as a port:*

```
interface CdcSignal_i(input clock);

    logic data;

    // To memory controller
    modport Master
    (
        input clock,
        output data
    );

    // To memory
    modport Slave
    (
        input clock,
        input data
    );

endinterface

module Cdc(
    CdcSignal_i.Slave slave,
    CdcSignal_i.Master master
);

    logic registerS;
    logic registerM;

    always_ff @(posedge slave.clock) begin
        registerS <= slave.data;
    end

    always_ff @(posedge master.clock) begin
        registerM <= registerS;
        master.data <= registerM;
    end

endmodule

module InterfaceTest(
    input logic clock0,
    input logic clock1,
    input logic data0,
    output data1);

    CdcSignal_i signal0(clock0);
    assign signal0.data = data0;

    CdcSignal_i signal1(clock1);
    assign data1 = signal1.data;

    Cdc cdc(signal0, signal1);

endmodule
```

[image: RTL for clock designed as a port]

*Clock as a signal:*

```
interface CdcSignal_i();

    logic data;
     logic clock;

    // To memory controller
    modport Master
    (
        input clock,
        output data
    );

    // To memory
    modport Slave
    (
        input clock,
        input data
    );

endinterface

module Cdc(
    CdcSignal_i.Slave slave,
    CdcSignal_i.Master master
);

    logic registerS;
    logic registerM;

    always_ff @(posedge slave.clock) begin
        registerS <= slave.data;
    end

    always_ff @(posedge master.clock) begin
        registerM <= registerS;
        master.data <= registerM;
    end

endmodule

module InterfaceTest(
    input logic clock0,
    input logic clock1,
    input logic data0,
    output data1);

    CdcSignal_i signal0();
    assign signal0.clock = clock0;
    assign signal0.data = data0;

    CdcSignal_i signal1();
    assign signal1.clock = clock1;
    assign data1 = signal1.data;

    Cdc cdc(signal0, signal1);

endmodule
```

[image: RTL for clock designed as a signal]

Answer (score 0):

You typically see a `Clock` as input port to an interface because that signal is shared among many other interface and module instances. On the other hand, each instance of your interface creates another instance of the signal `InData`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Is not the opposite situation possible? For example, if you connect `Clock`s of two interfaces to different clock sources they will be different nodes. On the other hand, if you connect `InData` of two interfaces together, they will represent a shared signal.

Comment: No. Remember we are talking about two independent *instances* of the same or different interfaces. There are no connections between separate instances unless you add code to make a connection. Try it.

Comment: I tried to synthesize two examples and see any difference there, but I cannot. Please see my original post.

Comment: The difference is in your use of extra continuous assignments.

Comment: So, you are saying that the only difference between them is how wires are connected to an interface (during instantiation or through the `assign` statement later)?

Comment: That's one interpretation. I find that using the `assign` with hierarchical references leads to poorer coding styles, and more chances for missing or improper connections.